# Phrase or expression meaning "getting more than you bargained for"

Tags: phrases, idioms, expressions

I'm writing an article and I'd appreciate a more sophisticated phrase for the term "getting more than you bargained for".

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Context please.

Comment: Do you mean something you've been involved into is resulting with (extras) unwanted consequences/reponsibilities?

Comment: BONUS! (actually much LESS sophisticated, so not a real answer to your questoin.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Getting more than you bargained for" itself is idiomatic but you could use "largesse" or "bounty" suitably, if what you received has positive value.

Also, you can check if you can use the phrase "unintended consequences" to suit your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Something like "He underestimated the implications/ramifications/impact of his actions", perhaps?

It's hard to reply without knowing the context though.

Answer (score 1):

According to **American Heritage** definition ([link](http://dictionary.reference.com/idioms/more%20than%20one%20bargained%20for))

> **more than one bargained for** — An unexpected outcome, especially an unfavorable one, as in *Serving on the board this year has involved more work than I bargained for*. This expression alludes to a higher than anticipated cost for a transaction. [Mid-1800s]

If **things have gone wrong** context is assumed then I suggest using

> **gone pear-shaped**: things have gone pear-shaped

Answer (score 1):

Well there is the very popular phrase "Biting off more than one can chew".

Also, I think you may find something useful in the following link.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/more

Answer (score -2):

Lagniappe, this is a term used in Louisiana that means getting more than you thought. A bonus or a gift.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that answers on this site are expected to be comprehensive, and should include suitable references and examples, and an explanation of any nuances. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help), then edit your submission as appropriate.